Looking for marketing campaign datasets
I'm doing research on how publishing content consistently on social media improves a company's brand awareness and having a hard time finding any marketing metrics data. Does anyone know of good marketing metrics datasets in BigQuery?
Thank you,
JulieB
I've used "marketing" and "marketing data" and "marketing metrics" in searches but didn't find the data. There doesn't seem to be much marketing related data.

I'm just learning BigQuery and I'm not entirely familiar with marketing data (datasets). I do highly recommend Kaggle website. They have tons of datasets including marketing data.
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets?search=marketing
Let me know if that helps!!!
-Jeff

Short answer:
It doesn't work like that. There is no direct relationship in the format "X" publications * "Y" views = "Z" result.
Long answer:
Social media and content consist of many paradigms, and if they existed, these formulas would be much more complex.
The mere fact of publishing any content with a brand mention is not a result.
First, you must clearly understand your market and your product. Then - study all the competitors, structure them, and identify direct and indirect competitors at all levels. The next task is to build a differentiation strategy between your product and your competitor's products. I mean differentiation at the consumer preferences and benefits level, not at the content level.
Next, you will have to analyze their work with content and define your own content strategy. And then endless hypotheses and tests await you - until you see that you have hit the target. This applies to content topics, design, types, frequency and time of publications, cross-publications on different platforms and other parameters.
As soon as your reach starts growing incredibly - congratulations: it's time to update your content strategy and change some of its parts. Because the audience quickly gets used to new things - and this means that you constantly need to be even newer for them. I recommend making such adjustments every three months if your content strategy and team are already working great and bringing the results I described earlier. Now, try to add hundreds and thousands of business areas, tens of thousands of services, millions of different products and brands, and billions of varying publication options, all impacting each potential audience. And if you can do this - of course, Google & BigQuery will be grateful to you for the work they are not able to cope with :) At least because the world is constantly changing, and social networks reflect its dynamics of change.
P.S.: The previous comment reminds me of the grey side of link promotion in dirty SEO.
